# Litespeed Port 80 (http) printing php code

Tags: litespeed, openlitespeed

I've very new to Litespeed and so far love it! All works amazingly fast on port 443(HTTPS), but on port 80 (HTTP) the browser prints the PHP code rather than executing it.

Can anyone point me in the right direction, I'm a bit of a noob and very new to servers.

This is what's running on port 80

```
root@openlitespeed-cuyg-vm:/home/info# netstat -tulpn | grep :80

tcp6       0      0 :::80     :::*       LISTEN      606/apache2
```

Many thanks

Comment: I once saw a server that apache is running on port 80 and didn't have php set up , so it gives code directly , check what is running on port 80

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I've added the answer to the question. Thanks

Comment: @qtwrk Apache was running on port 80, so I stopped apache. Not there's nothing listening on port 80. But I have the same problem still.

Comment: restart `systemctl restart lsws`  so it can bind to port 80

Comment: That worked! thank you!!! Can you add that as an answer so I can mark it as such.

Answer (score 0):

summary :

the case here is LiteSpeed runs on port 443, but Apache runs on port 80 , as OP's netstat output

and it seems the Apache did not configure the PHP properly , so it just outputs the source code

so the solution for OP was stop Apache to free port 80 , then restart LiteSpeed by `systemctl restart lsws` to make it bind to port 80